# rails server output - Excessive newlines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `rails s`-output, each line is followed by two empty lines. I don't know if this is intended or not but I find it highly uncomfortable to read.

The newlines exist in pure `rails s` output and in the actual `log/development.log`.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

What might be the cause of this? This also occurs on fresh projects.

**Update 1: Software info**

**OS:** OS X 10.9.2
**Ruby:**  ruby 2.1.1p76
**Rails:** rails 4.1.0
**Terminal:** iTerm2 1.0.0.20140518 + Terminal (OS X default)

Comment: Please give more details like the version of ruby/rails, the OS, the terminal software...

Comment: May I ask how this question qualifies for a downvote?

Comment: its intended that each request is clearly separated from the others, yes.